# Adding columns and data to table

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I am trying to run the following queries. When I run them separately the code executes correctly. When I run them together I get the error message:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>   Invalid column name 'TotOP'.
>
> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
>   Invalid column name 'TotPK'.

It's as if the first query has not run at all? - Any ideas

As a work around I know that I can generate all of the columns at the beginning and only partially populate the table leaving these final two columns empty until I run the second query however I am curious to know why these statements can be run separately but not together.

Query 1:

```
ALTER TABLE [fcgen].[RPD1yeardata]
     ADD [TotOP] DECIMAL (7,3) NULL, 
         [TotPK] DECIMAL (7,3) NULL;
```

Query 2:

```
UPDATE [fcgen].[RPD1yeardata]
SET [TotOP] = [1]+[2]+[3]+[4]+[5]+[6]+[7]+[8]+[9]+[10]+[11]+[12]+[13]+[14]+[39]+[40]+[41]+[42]+[43]+[44]+[45]+[46]+[47]+[48],
    [TotPK] = [15]+[16]+[17]+[18]+[19]+[20]+[21]+[22]+[23]+[24]+[25]+[26]+[27]+[28]+[29]+[30]+[31]+[32]+[33]+[34]+[35]+[36]+[37]+[38]
FROM [fcgen].[RPD1yeardata]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use GO after 1s query

```
ALTER TABLE [fcgen].[RPD1yeardata]
ADD [TotOP] DECIMAL (7,3) NULL, 
    [TotPK] DECIMAL (7,3) NULL;

Go

--Query 2:

UPDATE [fcgen].[RPD1yeardata]
    SET [TotOP] = [1]+[2]+[3]+[4]+[5]+[6]+[7]+[8]+[9]+[10]+[11]+[12]+[13]+[14]+[39]+[40]+[41]+[42]+[43]+[44]+[45]+[46]+[47]+[48],
        [TotPK] = [15]+[16]+[17]+[18]+[19]+[20]+[21]+[22]+[23]+[24]+[25]+[26]+[27]+[28]+[29]+[30]+[31]+[32]+[33]+[34]+[35]+[36]+[37]+[38]
    FROM [fcgen].[RPD1yeardata];
```

Comment: That's great, solved the problem. Just wondering under what circumstances the queries are sent as a batch, or is this always the case?